# jquery returns 404, url does not match initial value

Tags: jquery

I am trying to send an AJAX GET request with jQuery but it's returning a 404 error. I know the url I passed is valid. But somehow, it is not working. The url got changed somehow. Any advice?

```
let path = $SCRIPT_ROOT + statusURL;
console.log(path);
// prints this (valid url)
// http://0.0.0.0:5000/status/80140376-2881-4215-87c2-0265eae09a6e 
$.ajax({
    url: path,
    method: "GET",
    success: successCheckJobStatus
});
```

This is the error returned by jQuery:

`jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 GET http://0.0.0.0:5000/video/:%20http://0.0.0.0:5000/status/80140376-2881-4215-87c2-0265eae09a6e 404 (NOT FOUND)`

Comment: On on your network tab, does the request have the correct URL?

Comment: no, its the incorrect url